# Wordpress header.php displaying different CSS depending on page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently in the process of converting my website to a wordpress site..and I've run into a problem

My homepage's header uses a different class than my single_page header
They uses 2 different css IDs .

Right now I have the homepage which is using  inside my header.php
but what I want it to do is to display  when you're on a page (is_page) How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is conditional tags: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

```
if (is_page()) { do this }
elseif (is_front_page()) { do that }
else { do nothing? }
```

This question could help you also: [Detect the browsed page from url in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013054/detect-the-browsed-page-from-url-in-wordpress/5021199#5021199)

Comment: I'm aware of the conditional tags but I'm not sure what to pass in the parameter and stuff..